# Constantly Searching For Files All Day? Batch File?

Tags: node.js, bash

I'm wondering how I would achieve this? I want to constantly loop through a directory and if a files exist there delete it?

Could I do this in bash script or would I need to use something like nodejs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are searching for:

Firstly do:

**1)You tell to script to search about some files then if existed, remove them**

You can enter files like the script in below:

```
#!/bin/bash
LIST_FILE="
/path/to/file1
/path/to/file2
/path/to/file3
/path/to/file4
"
for file in $LIST_FILE
do
  if [ -a $file ];then
     rm -rf $file
     echo $file is removed
  fi
done
```

**2)It removes all files founded by `find` command**

```
find /path/to/files >> /path/to/LIST
```

then run the script and invoke it by saying `./script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
LIST_FILE=/path/to/LIST
for file in $LIST_FILE
do
  if [ -a $file ];then
     rm -rf $file
     echo $file is removed
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a script that sits in a loop whilst looking for the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

SLEEP_SECS=5
TARGET_FILE="filename"

while [ 1 ]; do
  find /path/to/file -type f -name "$TARGET_FILE" -exec rm {} \;
  sleep $SLEEP_SECS
done
```

TARGET_FILE can be changed to a wildcard e.g. "*.jpg". This would traverse all directories under `/path/to/file` to find the file. In this example, the script would run every 5 seconds.